# Few QT programming questions

Tags: c++, qt

I am a begginer to QT programming and as I tried creating a GUI application I encountered some issues and questions:

· I have a 'Client' class, that stores the data from clients. I made this class to be a Designer form class (as i want to create a window where the user can input the data). I made it so that the data is set when a button is clicked. My question is if a simple class that stores data should have a Designer form or if this two things should be done separately.

· Regarding the last question, when i create the "client" widget (the window that will open when the user wants to enter client data) I have to do it as a pointer 
Client window = new Client
window->show().
If not done this way, the widget opens and closes inmediately. But I have another class called "List" that is a template class. When I want to store the client object in a List, it doesn't work, as List doesn't accept pointers, but a concrete object (i hope you understand what i'm saying). What can I do to solve this? The best would be to be able to do this:
Client window;
window.show();
Without it closing.

· Should I make the whole app on main.cpp or mainwindow.cpp? I mean, all the functions that make the app work and the different variables needed, should they exist on main.cpp or mainwindow.cpp? What is the right way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your questions show a general lack of research as there are many tutorials on getting started with Qt. Once you have read some of those and have more specific questions you can ask those here.

Comment: Re. 3rd question: There is no "right" way to do it. A Qt-using program is simply a C++ program. Just that question alone would be way too broad for a C++ answer, you could write a book about it. You are asking, essentially, "how to design software".

Answer (score 1):

a) It is typically better to separate your data model from the user interface code. There are many reasons for this, but one very practical reason is that you will be able to use your model at different places as well - e.g. within automated tests.

b) With Qt you typically have a simple main.cpp file which sets up the application object and shows the main window. Thus you have separate files for this. I good example can be found in the "[Application example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html)" in the Qt docs:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(application);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setOrganizationName("QtProject");
    app.setApplicationName("Application Example");
    MainWindow mainWin;
    mainWin.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Your third question regarding the list template is hard to answer without knowing the context. Anyway, for keeping a simple list of objects you can use the QList template class which qt provides. Here is an example:

```
QList<QWidget *> list;
list.append(pMyWidget);
```